# Iterating through JSON array, accessing name for output and Id to set className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, iterator

I'm practicing doing api calls by fetching the fortnite upcoming items.

I am trying to access both the itemId and the name of the items within the json array which looks roughly like this:

```
data: Array(67)
0: {itemId: "bcc523f5-bef4-44eb-8855-35a1413b669c", lastUpdate: 1617619592, item: {…}}
1: {itemId: "723a761f-fa59-4cfc-92e7-9309a87c5a9e", lastUpdate: 1617585135, item: {…}
}
```

and then:

```
0:
item: {name: "Ruby Shadows", description: "Sometimes you gotta go dark.", type: "outfit", rarity: "epic", series: "shadow", …}
itemId: "bcc523f5-bef4-44eb-8855-35a1413b669c"
lastUpdate: 1617619592
__proto__: Object
```

I'm using .map to do so, but in some instances, the object literal inside `<h3 key={items.itemId}>` doesn't return the desired result. (currently returning undefined)

I've been cracking my head over it all afternoon. Still new to react.

My code:

```
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Shop() {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
    },[]);
    
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    let dataArray = [];
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');
      
      const items = await data.json();
      dataArray = items.data;
      setItems(dataArray.map( x => {return x}));
      console.log(items);
    }
   

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <h1>Upcoming Fortnite Items</h1>
      <div>
        {items.map(x => 
        <Link to={`/shop/${items.itemId}`}>
          <h3 key={items.itemId}>
          {x.item.name} 
          </h3>
          </Link>)}       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

I appreciate the help, thank you.

EDIT:

This is another component handling the component for the other p;age where the item details are supposed to be output: (sorry)

````
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function ItemDetail({ match }) {
  /**this puts it into effect */
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
        console.log(match);
    },[]);
    
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const fetchItem = await fetch(`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id={{itemid}}`);
        const item = await fetchItem.json();
    }

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <h1>Item</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;```
````

Comment: `setItems(dataArray.map( x => {return x}));` this is the same as `setItems(dataArray)`. Did you try to do something different here?

Comment: yea, I had it something like: ```setItems(dataArray.map( x => x.item);```

Comment: what is returning `await data.json()` ? Also avoid declaring `const items` twice, just for readability

Comment: @FabioLopez I didn't notice this. But that doesn't produce unwanted results, does it?

Comment: If you're saying `x.item` sometimes produces `undefined`, then console log `x` in those cases and see if the key is something else or some items must be skipped.

Comment: @junvar I'll try that

Comment: @T888 yeah don't worry about it, javascript by default chooses the closest scope variable. My advice is just so you don't mix both variables in the future

Comment: @junvar this is what I'm getting in the console.log(match):

```{path: "/shop/:id", url: "/shop/undefined", isExact: true, params: {…}}
isExact: true
params:
id: "undefined"
__proto__: Object
path: "/shop/:id"
url: "/shop/undefined"
__proto__: Object```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
return (
    <div id="App">
      <h1>Upcoming Fortnite Items</h1>
      <div>
        {items.map(x => 
        <Link to={`/shop/${items.itemId}`}> // <-------  Here 
          <h3 key={items.itemId}> //<-------- Here
          {x.item.name} 
          </h3>
          </Link>)}       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You need to get the `itemId` from each element, right now you are trying to get the value from the actual array, which doesn't contain any field and therefore is giving you `undefined`.

The code should look something like this:

```
return (
    <div id="App">
      <h1>Upcoming Fortnite Items</h1>
      <div>
        {items.map(x => 
        <Link to={`/shop/${x.itemId}`}>
          <h3 key={x.itemId}>
          {x.item.name} 
          </h3>
          </Link>)}       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Actually, that worked!!! Oh man, thank you so much! Made a typo earlier.

Comment: Btw, I just noticed that the key is not being set correctly and I am getting a ```index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.``` error

Comment: That's right, the key should be defined on the `Link` element, not on the `h3`.